# Laravel Left Join overrides the id column

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8.x and am trying to get some data from my database. I'm then joining another table, which is fine, except my ID column of my `reports` table is being overridden by my `report_data` column, the ID column there.

I've tried to use the `->select('report.*')`, which seems to preserve my ID column, but then I don't have my columns from my `report_data` table included in my left join?

What am I doing wrong?

```php
/**
 * View a report
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function view($id)
{

    $report = DB::table('reports')
                ->where('id', $id)
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->first();

    if (!empty($report->report_data_id)) {
      $report = DB::table('reports')
                  ->where('reports.id', $id)
                  ->where('reports.user_id', Auth::id())
                  ->leftJoin('report_data', 'report_data.id', '=', 'reports.report_data_id')
                  ->first();

      $report->discovery_filters = json_decode($report->discovery_filters);
      $report->report_data = json_decode($report->report_data);
    }

    return response()->json([
      'success' => true,
      'message' => 'Your report',
      'report' => $report
    ], 200);

}
```

I need to preserve the `id` column from my `reports` table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're selecting both the `id` columns, which is overriding the one of the id.
You can specify Eloquent to select the "id" column from "report_data" table AS "rd_id"
and make joins on that:

```
$report = DB::table('reports')
    ->select('reports.*', 'report_data.id AS rd_id')
    ->where('reports.id', $id)
    ->where('reports.user_id', Auth::id())
    ->leftJoin('report_data', 'report_data.id', '=','reports.report_data_id')
    ->first();
```

Then you can use the `report_data id` as:

```
$report->rd_id;
```

And the `report id` as:

```
$report->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$report = Report::find($id); //I guess that table have uniq value for IDs as default so you don't need 'where' checks.

if($report->report_data_id){

//Depend what columns you need, if you want all 'reports_data' columns then just add '.*' and replace id for it as bellow

  $report = Report::select('reports.*', 'reports_data.*', 'reports_data.id as rd_id')
                    ->join('reports_data', 'reports.report_data_id', 'reprots_data.id')
                    ->where('reports.id', $id)
                    ->where('reports.user_id', Auth::id())
                    ->first();
                    
  $report->discovery_filters = json_decode($report->discovery_filters);
  $report->report_data = json_decode($report->report_data);
  
}

// TRY dd($report) to see what is inside
// Your key from reports_data should be now 'rd_id'

return response()->json([
  'success' => true,
  'message' => 'Your report',
  'report' => $report
], 200);
```

Comment: Also, do you know that you can add relations like ->hasOne // ->hasMany in Report Model? Let me know if you need help with that